# Initializing static HashMap from driver class, and expanding its scope

Tags: java, static, hashmap, initialization

I am working on a school ATM Java assignment and I am stuck. In a sub class, **Bank**, I have a HashMap variable, **theBank** with a method **createAccount** for adding to the map. The interface is predetermined by the assignment specs, including the static state of the HashMap:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
public class Bank {

public static HashMap<String, BankCustomer> theBank;

public Bank ()
{
    theBank = new HashMap<String, BankCustomer> ();
}
/**
 * Method createAccount.
 * To add a new BankCustomer element to the HashMap.
 * Uses the account number as the key and the new BankCustomer as the value.
 * @param newCustomer to input a BankCustomer for the HashpMap 
 * 
 */
public void createAccount(BankCustomer newCustomer)
{
    if (newCustomer != null){   
        theBank.put(newCustomer.getAccountNumber(), newCustomer);
    }
}
```

I am required to initialize the HashMap in a method in the main driver class:

```
/**
 * Method initialize
 * To add Customer references to the Bank HashMap as seed data for testing
 */
public void initialize() 
{   
    Bank testBank = new Bank (); //initialize HashMap from Bank class

    //seed the HashMap with a few objects
    BankCustomer a = new BankCustomer("David", "Jones", "A001", "547");
    BankCustomer b = new BankCustomer("Alice", "Stone", "A002", "777"); 
    //seed the HashMap
    testBank.createAccount(a);
    testBank.createAccount(b);
}
```

This is the default constructor of the driver class (the run() method is the case/switch routine):

```
public class ATM {

/**
 * Default constructor of class ATM. 
 * Calls the initialize() method to seed the Bank with some BankCustomers. 
 * Calls the run() method to perform the primary program functions.
 */
public ATM ()
{
    initialize();
    run();  
}
```

The main driver method is:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[] args)
{
    new ATM();
}
```

My problem is that in my methods in class ATM, I am not able to access the Bank HashMap variable, **testBank**; the "testBank cannot be resolved." Here is one of the methods that testBank is not resolved:

```
/**
 * Method verifyCustomer
 * To confirm a BankCustomer's account number and passcode.
 * Called when the user is required to sign in to the application. 
 * Will set a boolean so the user does not have to sign in again during the session.
 */
public void verifyCustomer()
{
    InputReader reader = new InputReader ();
    boolean isVerified = false;
    if(isVerified ==  false){
        System.out.println("Enter Account Number: ");
        String accountNumber = reader.getStringInput();
        for(String accounts: testBank.keySet()){
            if(accounts.equals(accountNumber)){
                BankCustomer customer = testBank.get(accounts);
                String code = customer.getPasscode();
                System.out.println("Enter Passcode: ");
                String passcode = reader.getStringInput();
                if(code.equals(passcode)){
                    isVerified = true;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Incorrect passcode.");
                    isVerified = false;
                }
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Account not found.");
                isVerified = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I initializing the HashMap and seeding it correctly in the **initialize()** method?
Any suggestion why **testBank** is not resolved? How do I get the scope of the HashMap wide enough to be resolved in the ATM class methods?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Not sure if that will help but you could avoid initializing theBank inside construcor and initialize in field definition.

Comment: how about using getter and setter for map?

Comment: Are you using any IDE to work with Java? I ask this because if you would have an IDE you would have found this problem already and you would have known the cause immediatelly.

Answer (score 0):

From what you wrote in your question I see why that fails for you:

> public void initialize()  {
>       Bank testBank = new Bank (); //initialize HashMap from Bank class

This is where your problem starts. You created it in your local method, but then you don't keep it anywhere. You need to either have a private parameter or some other form of architecture. This simply will not work on compilation time.